# For which $p \in (1, \infty)$ can it be true that $2|x||y| \leq x^p + y^p$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For which $p \in (1, \infty)$ can it be true that $2|x||y| \leq x^p + y^p$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

The fact that this holds for $p = 2$ follows from

$$(|x|-|y|)(|x|-|y|) \geq 0$$
$$|x|^2 - 2|x||y| + y^2 \geq 0$$
$$x^2 + y^2 \geq 2|x||y|$$

How about for other $p$?

Comment: If $x, y <0$, then certainly it won't be true for odd $p$ and those $p$ for which $x^p,y^p \not\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Putting signs problems aside, this can only hold for $p=2$ (try $x=y=.1$ and $x=y=3$) and does hold for $p=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $p\gt 1$ is such that inequality  $2|x||y| \leqslant x^p + y^p$ holds for any $x,y\in\geqslant 0$. In particular, it holds for $x=y\geqslant 0$ hence we have for any positive $x$ the following inequality:
$$\tag{*}    x^2 \leqslant x^p .$$
If $p\gt 2$, then divide in (*) by $x^2$ and let $x$ go to zero (or small enough) to get a contradiction.

If $p\lt 2$, then divide in (*) by $x^p$ and let $x$ go to infinity (or large enough) to get a contradiction.

Finally, the equalily holds for $p=2$ since $\left(\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|\right)^2\geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's true for $p=2$ only because for real $p$ we need $x>0$ by definition of $x^p$ and our inequality can not hold for all reals $x$ and $y$.

If $p>2$ and odd then $x=y=-1$ gets a contradiction.

If $p>2$ and even then $x=y\rightarrow0^+$ gets a contradiction again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by $x^p$, then by definition.....So do you mean to say if we write $x^3$, then it must be that $x>0$??

Comment: yes I know that but your comment "....$x^p$ then by definition...."seems to be not conforming with that. Which "definition" are you referring to?

Comment: In fact you have NOT answered OP's query. OP is asking for which $p$ will this be true and OP has already shown it to be true for $p=2$. So your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Rather than rushing to the (anecdotal) sign problem in the statement of the question, one might correct it and show by an elementary argument why $p=2$ is then the only fit.

Comment: @Did I showed it. See better please my solution.

Comment: No, since, once the question is corrected, there is no reason to assume $p$ is an integer.

Comment: @Anurag A I fixed my post. See now please.